# Issue with modifying array by reference

Tags: php, session, reference, pass-by-reference

In PHP, I have the following code (whittled down, to make it easier to read):

```
class Var {
  public $arr;
  function __construct($arr) {
    $this->arr = $arr;
  }
  function set($k, $v) {
    $this->arr[$k] = $v;
  }
}

class Session extends Var {
  function __construct() {}
  function init() {
    session_start();
    parent::__construct($_SESSION);
  }
}

$s = new Session();
$s->init();
$s->set('foo', 'bar');

var_dump($_SESSION);
```

At this point, I want $_SESSION to contain `'foo' => 'bar'`. However, the $_SESSION variable is completely empty. Why is this the case? How can I store the $_SESSION variable as a property in order to later modify it by reference?

I have tried replacing `__construct($arr)` with `__construct(&$arr)`, but that did not work.

Comment: "but that did not work." --- it actually worked. But it wasn't enough to work as you expected.

Comment: Is it because you aren't declaring your `$arr` as `array()`? So in your `class` `Var` constructor, `$this->arr = $array();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You needed to take care of reference on **every** variable re-assignment you have.

So the first place is `__construct(&$arr)`

The second is `$this->arr = &$arr;`

Then it should work.

If you didn't put the `&` in the latter case - it would "make a copy" for the reference you passed in constructor and assign "a copy" to the `$this->arr`.

PS: It's really weird to call parent constructor from non-constructor method